# How do I join two tables together (one to many relationship), but only select the 3rd match from the second table?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have two tables, table A and table B. There are multiple entries in table B for each entry in table A when joining them together, but I only want to match the 3rd value from table B, which is neither the maximum nor the minimum of the values. The values can be ordered, and it will always be the 3rd value after ordering. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

[image: Example:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
  ranked_b AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY val) AS key_rank
  FROM
    table_b
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_a
INNER JOIN
  ranked_b
    ON  ranked_b.key = table_a.key
    AND ranked_b.key_rank = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select key, 
  array_agg(value order by value limit 3)[safe_ordinal(3)] as value
from tableA 
left join tableB 
on key = foreignkey
group by key
```

Comment: I'd love to know the relative performance against using row number. Regardless, I think this is now my preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.value
        from b
        where b.key = a.key
        limit 1 offset 2
       )
from a;
```